# How do I implement two interface in the same class depending on the condition without using any imports

Tags: java, interface

> I want to know how do I use 1 interface at one time when there is two interface in one class. For example, when Cube is not fixed() I can change it's length via interface properties. However, once it is fixed it only can access interface calculate which is volume() or area().

```java
public interface properties <T> {
    T size(int length);
    T fixed();
}

public interface calculate{
    int volume();
    int area();
}

public class Cube implements properties, calculate{
    private final int length;

    public Cube(int length){this.length = length;}

}
```

Comment: Interfaces in Java don't allow for conditionally exposing methods, you'll have to structure your logic in a different way. Like, throwing exceptions from the methods if fixed() has not been called first, or having a factory of Cubes that returns instances after they're fixed.

Comment: Sorry as I am quite new to this, what does it mean to have a factory of cubes that returns instances after they are fixed?

Comment: @Heartless I think Oscar refers to the factory design pattern (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm). I hope this will give u some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Factory of shape as mentioned would be my preference.

However, if you really want to control whenever you can start to use the computation methods -> I would suggest to throw an exception if the shape is not `fixed`, and manage that by inheritance, like

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
public abstract class Calculate {

    private boolean fixed = false;

    protected abstract int computeVolume();

    protected abstract int computeArea();

    public int volume() {
        if (!fixed) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("not yet fixed!");
        }
        return computeVolume();
    }

    public int area() {
        if (!fixed) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("not yet fixed!");
        }
        return computeArea();
    }

}
```

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
public class Cube extends Calculate {

    private int length;

    @Override
    protected int computeVolume() {
        return length * length * length;
    }

    @Override
    protected int computeArea() {
        return 6 * (length * length);
    }
}
```

Here are some unit tests to validate:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class CubeTest {

    @Test
    public void testCubeWhenFixed() {
        Cube cube = new Cube();
        cube.setLength(4);
        cube.setFixed(true);

        int vol = cube.volume();
        assertEquals(64, vol);
    }

    @Test (expected = UnsupportedOperationException.class)
    public void testCubeWhenNotFixed() {
        Cube cube = new Cube();
        cube.setLength(4);

        int vol = cube.volume();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't represent the fixedness of a `Cube` at the type level, your code will be much more difficult to maintain.

I would have a mutable `CubeBuilder` which just has:

```
class CubeBuilder {
  private int length;
  public void setLength(int newLength) { this.length = newLength; }
  public Cube build() { return new Cube(length); }
}
```

and then an immutable `Cube` which has `volume` and `area`.

Otherwise, as you work on your program, you will never be quite sure which methods it's OK to pass a non-fixed `Cube` to, and whether a given `Cube` reference is fixed or non-fixed.